# Criar contador sequencial

Tags: r, loop

Estou precisando criar uma coluna de contagem de ocorrências de um valor presente em outra coluna. Como, por exemplo, contagem na coluna "y" de elementos presentes na coluna "x":

```
    x     y
1   A     1
2   B     1
3   A     2
4   C     1
5   B     2
6   A     3
```

Provavelmente terei de criar algum loop, mas não consegui desenvolver algo eficiente.
Normalmente se considera apenas o resultado final do contador (como um contador de ocorrências mesmo). Porém, preciso de em algum tipo de contador que "guarde" todas as etapas da contagem, para criar um número de identificação para cada ocorrência.

Comment: Só para entender, vc quer agrupar os dados por y e contar os valores de x dentro de cada grupo, correto?

Answer (score 4):

Não é necessário criar um loop. Dá pra resolver este problema usando o pacote `dplyr`:

```
dados <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
  .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = "x", 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
dados %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(y = 1:n())

# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   x [3]
        x     y
   <fctr> <int>
 1      A     1
 2      C     1
 3      B     1
 4      B     2
 5      B     3
 6      C     2
 7      C     3
 8      C     4
 9      B     4
10      B     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema é tranquilo, e como o Marcus disse, o `dplyr` dá conta do recado. Mas eu achei a solução dele não muito geral.

O seguinte código conta as ocorrências de `x` em cada grupo de `y` (note que alterei levemente a sua matriz para surgir uma contagem maior que 1).

```
df <- 
    data.frame(
    x = c('A', 'B', 'A','C','B','A', 'A'),
    y = c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1)
)

df %>% 
    group_by(y, x) %>% 
    count()
```

Resultando em:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   y, x [6]
      y      x     n
    <dbl> <fctr> <int>
1     1      A     2
2     1      B     1
3     1      C     1
4     2      A     1
5     2      B     1
6     3      A     1
```

Outra maneira de se contar os elementos de um grupo é usando a função `n()` dentro de um `summarise`:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(y, x) %>% 
    summarise(contagem = n())
```

O resultado é o mesmo que o anterior.
Se você precisar separar o tabela em diversas tabelas menores, de acordo com os valores de y, você pode fazer assim:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(y, x) %>% 
    count %>% 
    split(.$y)
```

Resultando em uma lista de `tibbles` (facilmente convertível para `data frames`):

```
$`1`
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   y, x [3]
      y      x     n
    <dbl> <fctr> <int>
1     1      A     2
2     1      B     1
3     1      C     1

$`2`
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   y, x [2]
      y      x     n
    <dbl> <fctr> <int>
1     2      A     1
2     2      B     1

$`3`
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   y, x [1]
      y      x     n
    <dbl> <fctr> <int>
1     3      A     1
```

Comment: Acabei utilizando o dplyr sugerido pelo Marcus. Vou tentar por esta sua via também, Guilherme. Agradeço a vocês.